# in Rust macroquad engine, how to make sure one moving direction is selected

Tags: rust, game-development

im coding a snake game in rust to learn the macroquad engine, im still a rust beginner and really interested in the language

the problem is i dont seem to be able to make the snake go in a single direction, like if the head is going up, dont go down at the same time

here is the update method used on the head of the snake

```
 pub fn update(&mut self, dt: f32) {
    let v_mv = match (is_key_down(KeyCode::Down), is_key_down(KeyCode::Up)) {
        (true, false) => 1f32,
        (false, true) => -1f32,
        _ => 0f32,
    };
    let h_mv = match (is_key_down(KeyCode::Right), is_key_down(KeyCode::Left)) {
        (true, false) => 1f32,
        (false, true) => -1f32,
        _ => 0f32,
    };
    self.player.x += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * h_mv;
    self.player.y += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * v_mv;
}
```

there is nothing preventing the snake from moving in x and y at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would merge the two `match`es:

```rust
pub fn update(&mut self, dt: f32) {
    let (v_mv, h_mv): (f32, f32) = match (
        is_key_down(KeyCode::Down),
        is_key_down(KeyCode::Up),
        is_key_down(KeyCode::Right),
        is_key_down(KeyCode::Left),
    ) {
        (true, false, false, false) => (1.0, 0.0),
        (false, true, false, false) => (-1.0, 0.0),
        (false, false, true, false) => (0.0, 1.0),
        (false, false, false, true) => (0.0, -1.0),
        _ => (0.0, 0.0),
    };

    self.player.x += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * h_mv;
    self.player.y += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * v_mv;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it, although i will work on a more idiomatic function later :)